# How convert needed SQL query to Elastic DSL

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an index with 19 mapped fields and I need to query it with query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my-index 
WHERE field1 IN (value1, value2) 
  AND field2 IN (valueX, valueY, valueZ) 
  AND *anyOfThe19Fields* 
CONTAINS '2-f2d2cd00-8990-11ec-95bc-000d3a2d1528';
```

I really can't figure out how I can implement something like that with a single query.

I would appreciate your help, thx

Comment: did you try to use the sql translate api? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html anyway, it should be possible to implement the query

Comment: Yes I tried with _sql/translate but only some SQL keywords are supported, so this is not fitting my requirements.

I was thinking exactly to implementing it manually, how would you do?

Comment: Can you share what is the mapping of these fields use GET /{index-name}/_mapping

Comment: I think I got the solution: I implemented my custom repository and manually built the query. The generated DSL is very much similar to the one proposed by @ESCoder.
Thx anyone

Comment: hi @a.hermes , did you complete your solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your SQL query you need to use this elasticsearch query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "field1": [
              "value1",
              "value2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "field2": [
              "valueX",
              "valueY",
              "valueZ"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "2-f2d2cd00-8990-11ec-95bc-000d3a2d1528"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```